# How do I get Type

Tags: types, go

I'd like to get (reflect)type from type name.
http://play.golang.org/p/c-9IpSafx0

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Name string

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")

    var name Name = "Taro"
    fmt.Println(name)

    fmt.Println(getType(name))
    // fmt.Println(getType(Name))  // want to same as getType(name)
}

func getType(v interface{}) reflect.Type {
    return reflect.TypeOf(v)
}
```

How do I rewrite getType function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to pass a type as an argument to a function in Go, so what you ask is not possible.  If you want to use the `reflect` module to work with types, you will need to have a value as a starting point.

Comment: You can get methods by name. I wonder if there is reason to not allow finding types by name or if it was an oversight.

Answer (score 0):

As @James Henstridge said, you can't pass a type to a function in go.  However if you have a composite type then you can create a `nil` version of it very easily and pass that instead. ([play](http://play.golang.org/p/0FuSjfQ4jm))

```
type Name struct{ name string }

func main() {
    var name = Name{"Taro"}
    fmt.Println(name)

    fmt.Println(getType(name))
    fmt.Println(getType(Name{})) // want to same as getType(name)
}

func getType(v interface{}) reflect.Type {
    return reflect.TypeOf(v)
}
```

That said, I can't see why you'd want to do this, since you know what type you've got when you pass it into the `getType()` function, so you know its name, so why not just use it?

Comment: It is clear in this sample.But, real is not clear.
For example, a function has some arguments are not clear.